# Inverse Kinematics Not Working. Leg freaks out

Tags: animation

So i am trying to IK Rig my character and i added knneIK and heelIK bones. When i add the iverse kinematics modifier to the shin bone it freaks out like crazy.

[image: Here you can see the Ik modifier properties]

Here's what happens when i try to move the HeelIK Bone:
https://gyazo.com/24c3c96dbeb02493c0bf6b10dd143dba
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please share your armature: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6279" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6279/)

Comment: there are no more IK on your bone, also you should switch the direction of your legs, they go go from bottom to top while they should go the inverse way (head to the top -> tail to the bottom), but I may miss something?

Comment: Oh yeah i didn't send the IK rigged one. I just sent the normal one. Do you want me to sent the IK rigged one? Also how do i invert the bones?

Comment: to invert bone direction, go in Edit mode and Armature menu > Switch Direction. Yes please share the IK one

Comment: Ok so I will share the IK rigged file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6282" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6282/) Also when i switch sides of the bones it doesen't work. each bone just controls a part of the body and that part only. You can try switching sides of the legs and you will see.

Answer (score 1):

To sum it up, here is how it should be organized:

- In *Edit* mode, switch *Lowerleg* and *Thigh* directions (header menu > *Armature* > *Switch Direction*) so that it looks like in my picture.
- Parent *Thigh* to *Hip*, parent *Lowerleg* to *Thigh*, parent Foot to *Controller*, deparent *Controller*, deparent *Poletarget*, deactivate the *Deform* option of *Controller* and *Poletarget*.
- Bend the knee a bit forward.
- In *Pose* mode give an *IK* constraint to *Lowerleg* with the *Controller* as *Target* and *Poletarget* bone as *Pole Target*. Correct the *Pole Angle* if it needs to.

[image]

Comment: Alright so here's how the leg is supposed to work: https://gyazo.com/719c39b724c95baf75430422c81b2810. This is how it behaves when i switch teh directions of the thighs and the lowerlegs: https://gyazo.com/dac552071d8f3ba0f9f6bb87836c4cf3 Sorry but i'm new to blender and i don't know a lot about it. How can i fix that?

Comment: Also there is not hip bone for my rig.

Comment: I mean the thigh is called hip but there is not actual hip bone.

Comment: you don't follow my instructions, the bones are supposed to be parented, and the controller is supposed to be... the controller. And when I talk about the hip I'm talking about the bone called "pelvis" in your current armature. But maybe you should follow some tutorials about the basics of rigging, Ik constraints, etc...   ;)